# How to Retry Pentaho Job Step if Error

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a Kettle Job in Pentaho that has a SFTP Put step. This step connects to an SFTP server and places a file there. However, every so often, the connection fails and thereby results in a failure. I want to set up the job such that it retries the step twice upon failing before quitting. Is there a way for me to set up the job so that it does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by checking for a file. If there's no file, it's false and another path of the job will be taken. You can "go around" and start a new try.

Check for something in the Job, for example: "If file exists" under "Conditions"

Then: Two hops go in different directions (true, false)
if false, you could use the step "wait for" (under conditions with a maximum timeout for a quit), then place a dummy-Step right before your SFTP-Step to retry

It could look like this:
[image]

Comment: I presumed that there was a 'Retry' step somewhere, but this works too! Thanks for enlightening me about the 'Dummy' step - that's new to me.